# KineticJs group.setSize(300,300) not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to change size of kinetic group. but it gives JavaScript error message.

in kinetic js document its written than setSize works with group nodes

Comment: can you put your sample code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the documents are a bit outdated in that respect. Groups do not have a drawFunc so they do not have a width or height. If they ever do get width and height, it will be possible to create clipped groups, which will be nice. However, as they are now, groups are simply used to define a relative x and y starting coordinate for objects contained within them. This makes moving several objects at once possible (dragging, moveTo, event handlers, etc...), but that's about it.

[JsFiddle as requested](http://jsfiddle.net/uPaT3/2/)

```
var group = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 220,
    y: 40,
    draggable: true
});
```

Just make your group draggable and add your objects to the group.

Comment: Can i plz add code in jsfiddle for  to move several objects at once. Mainly there will be image and anchors in a group

Answer (score 0):

The code below will allow you to create a group with clipping properties.
Instantiate it like a group, where width and height is your clipping box.

```
Kinetic.Clipper = function(config) {
    this._initGroup(config);
};
Kinetic.Clipper.prototype = {
    _initGroup: function(config) {
        this.nodeType = 'Group';
        Kinetic.Container.call(this, config);
    },
    drawScene: function() {
        if(this.isVisible()) {

            var context = this.getLayer().getContext();
            var width = this.getWidth(), height = this.getHeight();
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(0, 0, width, height);
            context.clip();

            var children = this.children, len = children.length;
            for(var n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                children[n].drawScene();
            }

            context.restore();
        }
    },
};
Kinetic.Global.extend(Kinetic.Clipper, Kinetic.Container);
```

Comment: can you plz put an example in jsFiddle?

Comment: Especially an example where the group is not at (0,0), which I can't get to work.

Answer (score 0):

Document is outdated or wrong. 
It is not possible to directly change group size