# Resize a Kinetic.Group()

Tags: kineticjs

I have a Kinetic.Group() created. And I have added some Images to the Group.

```
    var TestGroup = Kinetic.Group();
    TestGroup.add(SomeImage);
    TestGroup.add(SomeOtherImage);
```

Now I want to re-size this group as a whole. I tried using

```
    TestGroup.setSize(100,100);
```

But it is not working. Can anyone help to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean that it isn't rendered using the new size? try to redraw the layer,

Comment: it has to be rendered with the new size. I tried redrawing the layer but the change in size has not effected the group.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using scale? If what you want is to make all nodes in a group look bigger on the canvas.

Comment: its a duplicate of below question I have asked
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097688/kineticjs-group-setsize300-300-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I think Jonke is correct - try using:

```
TestGroup.setScale(1.5, 1.5);
```

and then redraw if you want the objects inside the group to get visibly bigger.

If all you want is to resize the Group, it doesn't necessarily mean that it should show any visible change.